# How to not allowed taking in a number into a variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Given a string S of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1 , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as  space-separated strings on a single line (see the Sample below for more detail).
Sample Input:

```
2
Hacker
Rank
```

Sample output:

```
Hce akr
Rn ak
```

explanation:

> S="Hacker" S[0]="H", S[1]="a", S[2]= "c", S[3]="k", S[4]="e", S[5]="r"

However, with the following code I haven't been able to complete the challenge. How do I constraint taken input as an integer?

```
S = gets.chomp.chars.to_a


for i in 0..S.length
  if i%2 == 0
    s1 = S[i]
  else
    s2 = S[i]
  end
end

puts s1.to_s + " " + s2.to_s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic algorithm that would take O(n).

```
tests = gets.to_i

# run the loop for number of tests given
tests.times do
  string = gets.chomp # sanitize string from input, i.e. removes \n \r
  s_length = string.length # String length N
  new_string = " " * s_length # create of string of length N
  even_index = 0 # because evens are going to come first
  odd_index = s_length - (s_length/2) + 1 # odds are going to start where even numbers end + 1
  0.upto(s_length-1) do |i|
    if i%2 == 0
      new_string[even_index] = string[i]
      even_index += 1
    elsif
      new_string[odd_index] = string[i]
      odd_index += 1
    end
  end
  puts new_string
end
```

Benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

def using_ugly_algo(tests, string)
  # tests = gets.to_i

  tests.times do
    string = string
    s_length = string.length # String length N
    new_string = " " * s_length # creat of string of length N
    even_index = 0
    odd_index = s_length - (s_length/2) + 1
    0.upto(s_length-1) do |i|
      if i%2 == 0
        new_string[even_index] = string[i]
        even_index += 1
      elsif
        new_string[odd_index] = string[i]
        odd_index += 1
      end
    end
    # new_string
  end
end

def with_partition(amount, string)
  amount.times do
    input = string
    (input.split('').partition.with_index do |_, i|
      i.even?
    end.map(&:join).join(' '))
  end
end


n = 10_000
string = (0...500).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join

Benchmark.bmbm(100) do |x|
  x.report("using_ugly_algo "){ n.times { using_ugly_algo(5, string) } }
  x.report("with_partition  "){ n.times { with_partition(5, string) } }
end
```

Report:

```
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
using_ugly_algo                                                                                       13.790000   0.030000  13.820000 ( 13.843560)
with_partition                                                                                        16.790000   0.030000  16.820000 ( 16.830992)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ total: 30.640000sec

                                                                                                           user     system      total        real
using_ugly_algo                                                                                       13.930000   0.060000  13.990000 ( 14.070378)
with_partition                                                                                        18.640000   0.210000  18.850000 ( 19.392816)
```

Comment: Besides it is absolutely not idiomatic ruby, I believe it will fail on strings having odd amount of letters. Also, when you say `O(n)` it worth it to mention what `n` is in this particular case.

Comment: @mudasobwa It won't fail. I have tested before posting it. Also, if you're into software then everybody knows what  `n` is in o(n). Besides, just because we're so used to ruby's syntactic sugar, let's not just forget the basics. If it's done using `map` then `join` and then another operation like partition, then I am wasting cycles. Think of such operations on a large string, let's say 10^10, your solution will take a lot of time to calculate the answer.

Comment: “let's say 10^10,”—typed in the console? The code should solve the problem, not be trying to be a swiss knife. Using sophisticated algorithms here is a perfect example of premature optimization, leading to unreadable and, in general, bad code with a smell.

Comment: See the updated answer to understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: You are trying to say that to yield 18% of productivity, counted in μs (if not ns,) is worth adding a cumbersome logic entangling future readers. This is basically wrong.

Comment: Each second counts. If that sounds wrong to a programmer then I am sure they should invest some time thinking about the way they do things. Also, it's about 40-43% faster than the other answer, not 18%.

Comment: If I needed to be as fast as possible on parsing such strings, I would write a specific method in `c` as ruby extension. Trying to gain μs profit _still using ruby_ just shows up that the programmer has barely no understanding on what he is doing.

Comment: Well, that's a different topic altogether, would definitely like to talk about it. Let me know if wanna discuss about it over chat.

Comment: @mudasobwa, you should say "bad code with a *bad* smell". Without the second "bad" the reader might think you mean the smell of, say, freshly-baked bread, rather than that of a beached whale.

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
def doit(str)
  str.each_char.each_slice(2).with_object(['','']) do |(c_even, c_odd), (s_even, s_odd)|
    s_even << c_even
    s_odd  << c_odd unless c_odd.nil?
  end.join(' ')
end
```

**Examples**

```
doit "abracadabra"
  #=> "arcdba baaar" 
doit "Jack be nimble, Jack be quick"
  #=> "Jc enml,Jc eqik akb ibe akb uc"
```

**Explanation**

For

```
str = "abracadabra"

enum0 = str.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "abracadabra":each_char>
```

We can convert the enumerator `enum0` to an array to see what values it will generate:

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> ["a", "b", "r", "a", "c", "a", "d", "a", "b", "r", "a"] 

enum1 = enum0.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "abracadabra":each_char>:each_slice(2)> 
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["a", "b"], ["r", "a"], ["c", "a"], ["d", "a"], ["b", "r"], ["a"]] 

enum2 = enum1.with_object(['',''])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "abracadabra":each_char>:each_slice(2)>
  #   :with_object(["", ""])> 
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[["a", "b"], ["", ""]], [["r", "a"], ["", ""]], [["c", "a"], ["", ""]],
  #    [["d", "a"], ["", ""]], [["b", "r"], ["", ""]], [["a"], ["", ""]]]
```

If you examine the return values obtained when constructing `enum1` and `enum2`, you will see that they can be thought of as "compound" enunerators.

The first element of `enum2` is generated and passed to the block, assigning values to the four block variables<sup>1</sup>:

```
(c_even, c_odd), (s_even, s_odd) = enum2.next
       #=> [["a", "b"], ["", ""]] 
c_even #=> "a" 
c_odd  #=> "b" 
s_even #=> "" 
s_odd  #=> ""
```

The block calculation is now performed.

```
s_even << c_even
  #=> "a"
s_odd << c_odd unless c_odd.nil?
  #   s_odd << c_odd unless false
  #   s_odd << c_odd
  #=> "b"
```

The return values `"a"` and `"b"` are the new values of `s_even` and `s_odd`, respectively.

Now the next element of `enum_2` is generated, passed to the block and the block calculations are performed:

```
(c_even, c_odd), (s_even, s_odd) = enum2.next
  #=> [["r", "a"], ["a", "b"]] 
s_even << c_even
  #   "a" << "r"
  #=> "ar" 
s_odd << c_odd unless c_odd.nil?
  #   s_odd << c_odd unless "a".nil?    
  #   s_odd << c_odd
  #=> "ba"
```

Calculations continue in this way until the last value of `enum2` is generated: `["a"]`. This has the effect of assigning `nil` to `c_odd`, so the second line of the block is not executed<sup>2</sup>. Lastly, the array of two strings is joined with a separating space.

**Another way**

```
def doit(str)
  str.each_char.with_index.with_object(' ') { |(c,i),s|
    s.insert(i.even? ? s.index(' ') : s.size, c) }
end

doit "abracadabra"
  #=> "arcdba baaar"
```

<sup>1 The following expression employs *parallel assignment* (sometimes called *multiple assignment*) and *disambiguation* (sometimes referred to as *decomposition*) to assign values to the variables.</sup>

<sup>2 The second line could alternatively be written `s_odd << c_odd.to_s` or `s_odd << c_odd || ''`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

First input should be treated as an integer (namely, the amount of following strings to come):

```
amount = gets.to_i
```

Now we are to get `amount` strings and do our job (using [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)):

```
amount.times do
  input = gets.chomp
  puts (input.split('').partition.with_index do |_, i|
    i.even?
  end.map(&:join).join(' '))
end
```

Comment: Nice use of `partition`. I would probably have used two separate lines: `odd, even = input.each_char.partition.with_index(1) { |_, i| i.odd? }` and `puts "#{odd.join} #{even.join}"` but that's just a matter of personal preference. (I don't like adding method calls to `end`)

Answer (score 1):

Note that instead of inspecting each character's index, you could also use [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
'Hacker'.scan(/(.)(.?)/) #=> [["H", "a"], ["c", "k"], ["e", "r"]]
        .transpose       #=> [["H", "c", "e"], ["a", "k", "r"]]
        .map(&:join)     #=> ["Hce", "akr"]
        .join(' ')       #=> "Hce akr"
```

Or, using temporary variables:

```
s1 = ''
s2 = ''
'Hacker'.scan(/(.)(.?)/) { |a, b| s1 << a ; s2 << b }
puts "#{s1} #{s2}"
```

Comment: Nice one, Stefan. I initially tried something similar but didn't think of `?` in `(.?)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem you are having is, if I am using the right term, a usage error.  Your code is setting s1 and s2 to whatever the last checked letter is instead of concatenating.  Modifying you code, I suppose what you are looking for is something like this:

```
S = gets.chomp.chars.to_a
s1 = ""
s2 = ""

for i in 0...S.length 
    if i%2 == 0 
        s1.concat(S[i])
    else
        s2.concat(S[i])
    end
end

puts s1.to_s + " " + s2.to_s
```

Comment: `0..S.length` is wrong, there should be triple-dot non-greedy range: `0...S.length`.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't remember which it was so I just assumed he got that part right.  Though I realize now I only answered part of his question, forgot to exclude number entries.